# Can I use nosetests with the Parallel Test Executor in Jenkins?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nose

I'm trying to figure out if it is at all possible to use the [Parallel Test Executor](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parallel-test-executor) plugin in Jenkins with nosetests. I'm using Jenkins pipeline and following the demo, I'm running this:

```
def splits = splitTests parallelism: [$class: 'CountDrivenParallelism', size: 2], generateInclusions: true
def branches = [:]
for (int i = 0; i < splits.size(); i++) {
    def num = i
    def split = splits[num]
    branches["split${num}"] = {
      stage("Test Section #${num + 1}") {
        node() {
          stage('Preparation') {
            writeFile file: "parallel-test-includes-${i}.txt", text: split.list.join("\n")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
parallel branches
```

The resulting file contains tests that look like this:

```
path/to/file(without .py)/<class name>.java
path/to/file(without .py)/<class name>.class
```

Is it possible to use this output to include/exclude tests in nosetests? I don't see any options to do this in `nosetests --help`

Answer (score 0):

you can use nose-exclude plugin and pass a file to nose.

also you'll need to `split.collect { it.replaceAll(/(.*)\/(.*).(java|class)/, '$1.$2')}` and also use a Set to avoid duplicates.